# com.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Cannot find GOOGLE appId for project: <project-ID>>. ]

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-signin

I am trying to implement google sign in using firebase on android.
I can get user details by google signin api but could not authenticate user account via firebase.

On completion task success is false and exception is "**can't find the google app id for project**"

Whereas I have already enabled:

1. google signin from console.
2. Tracked project id via cloud console.
3. Included the latest config.json
4. Included SHA1 for debug and release variants

Anything else which must be done or any leads towards solution?

Below is my response log:

```
signInWithCredential:failure com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred.
[ Cannot find GOOGLE appId for project: <project-ID> ]
```

Comment: can you add your dependencies?

Comment: App level:
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



PROJECT Level:
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: change 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'  to 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'

Comment: Done! but no difference

Comment: So you added Google-services.json file ?

Comment: Yes i did that too